# Ionic Real Android Device light offs while playing Video in iframe

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am using ionic to display videos in an `iframe`. I have tried using ionic's `Insomnia` and `Blacklight`, yet to no avail. When I play the video on an Android device, the screen goes dark after 30 seconds while the video keeps playing. How can I prevent the screen from going dark? For example when I use the YouTube app, my screen stays on the entire time without doing anything.

**home.html**

```
<p> This is the Iframe in Html File </p>
<p>
<iframe width="100%" height="370" (click)="keepAlive()" [src]="video.video | youtube" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</p>
```

**home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { VideoPlayer , VideoOptions} from '@ionic-native/video-player';
import { Insomnia } from '@ionic-native/insomnia';
import { Backlight } from '@ionic-native/backlight';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {
  videos: any[] = [
    {
      video: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/e234gfdd?autohide=1&playsinline=1&showinfo=0',
      title: 'demo1'
    },
    {
      video: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/3erghj75?autohide=0&playsinline=1&showinfo=0',
      title: 'demo 2'
    }
  ];

  videoOpts : VideoOptions ;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController ,private backlight: Backlight,
    public videoPlayer : VideoPlayer,public insomnia: Insomnia) {

  }

  keepAlive() {
    console.log("called");
    this.backlight.on().then(() => console.log('backlight on'));

      this.insomnia.keepAwake()
      .then(
        () => console.log('success'),
        () => console.log('error keepAlive')
      );
  }

  sleepNow() {
      this.insomnia.allowSleepAgain()
      .then(
        () => console.log('success'),
        () => console.log('error sleepNow')
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it helped me.

import { Insomnia } from '@ionic-native/insomnia';

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController ,public insomnia: Insomnia) {
this.insomnia.keepAwake()
      .then(
        () => console.log('success'),
        () => console.log('error keepAlive')
      );
}